# Sorting array of 2^x words in real-time

Tags: fpga, verilog

I am presented with the following problem:

I have 256 12-bit words.  Each of them are initialized to the same (arbitrary) value.  At any given time, a subset of these words will either increase or decrease by the same quantity.  For example, 56 of the 256 words at one FPGA clock cycle may increase/decrease by `n`, while the 200 others remain unchanged.  Of these 56, each one of them experiences the same amount of addition or subtraction.

So, into this system, there are 512 bits which enable control over the 256 words. There is also an additional input, the incrementer, `inc`, which is common to all the words.  If the control bits of a single word, `word1`, are `01`, then `word1` adds `inc` to itself.  If the control bits are `10`, `word1` subtracts `inc` from itself.  If the control bits are `00`, then `word1` remains the same.

Knowing that all 256 words start in the same, arbitrarily defined state, and that they change predictably, as determined by their control signals and `inc`, I am wondering if there is a hardware-efficient means to sort all 256 words on-the-fly.

I hope my question makes sense, and please let me know if I can provide further information of my question statement. Thank you!

Comment: search Quicksort

Comment: That is a little bit hard to follow. It sounds like you have an array of 12 bit words. It also sounds like at any given time, there are at most 2 unique values stored in the array. Why do you need to sort the array? It seems like it would be enough to just count how many elements have value1 and how many have value2. I can easily imagine that some synchronization could be an issue here. Hopefully you don't need to sort in one clock cycle.

Comment: I think it is key to understand why you are sorting. Because maybe there is a better way. Do you really need to keep all the array elements in the sorted list? Or are you just sorting them to extract the max and/or the min? Or do you need population statistics like how many have value X and how many have value Y, etc.

Comment: I have an array (256 elements) of 12-bit words, which are initialized identically and arbitrarily.  I can choose `n` of these words, using the 512-bit control sequence, to have `inc` either added to or subtracted from each of the `n` respective words.  In practice, there will never be an 'add' and 'subtract' command issued at the same time; all of the selected words will either 'add' or 'subtract'  `inc` to or from, respectively, to themselves

My hope was that the knowledge of the control bits as well as `inc` would enable me to have a continually-updated sorted list of the words..

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No, this is not homework. It's a project I'm working on

Comment: `is the 512 bit control sequence parallel or serial,

Comment: It is in parallel

Comment: There is quite extensive literature on sorting techniques already.

Comment: so you're looking at a very expensive FPGA just to handle the I/O

Comment: You've never explained exactly what "real time" means to you. I take it that you want a fresh sort every time the 256 registers get updated. How often does that occur in terms of clock cycles? And how much latency in getting the results can you tolerate -- tens, hundreds or thousands of clock cycles? Do the results need to be presented in parallel, or can they be delivered sequentially?

Comment: I suppose real-time is ambiguous... Let's say a complete sort within 500 FPGA clock cycles. The goal is to have them completely sorted using as little hardware as possible

Comment: How often do the registers get updated? And how do the results need to be delivered?

Comment: it sounds like 500 clock cycles is the acceptable latency. What is the acceptable update rate? Do you need a new sorted array every clock cycle with up to 500 cycles latency, or one snapshot every 500 clock cycles?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard for me to understand what you mean by sorting them in hardware. This looks like a typical computer science class problem, where you need to make up some algorithm, that won't have to go through each and all of value to sort them but kinda shortcut. There is an interesting way of sorting on the bit level (in software). What's cool, it's a linear algorithm, not even square (correct me if I'm wrong about that, last time I saw that thing in university many years ago, never had a need to implement it).

I assume you sort ascending, but it doesn't really matter, you can flip it around.

You sort by each bit. First the most significant bit. Values with 0 MSB come first. Then those with MSB=1. Then within each group you recursively place those with 2ndMSB=0 first and 2ndMSB=1. And then recursively for the next bits. So you pretty much look at every number only number-of-bits-times.

Comment: It's called "[radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)" and it does work in linear time.

Comment: not actually linear because you need several passes proportional to the key length which is typically order log(n) - so radix sort is still \$ O(n.log(n) ) \$

Comment: @Jasen: "Big O" notation refers only to the number of items. In this case, the fact that multiple passes are required, depending on the radix value, is just a multiplicative constant.

Comment: Thanks for getting me thinking about radix sort again. I have a similar problem, in that I need to sort 1024 items of 24 bits each in hardware. In my case, the data arrives sequentially and the results can be delivered sequentially, and I can afford to spend a few thousand clock cycles doing it. In this case, I think that a rad-256 sort can be done in 3840 clock cycles, which beats my previous approach, merge sort, which takes 10240 clock cycles.

Answer (score 0):

OK so have 2^8 cells, each cell emists a signal on one of 2^12 lines depending on its value make the signal lines suppressable but a flag in the cell that has a global reset.

this are grouped into 2^12 rows of 2^8 bits

Each row is *or*ed together to indicate if any cell has that value  and a priority encoder with 2^12 inopus indicates the first populated row.

Use the priority encode to find the first row, then use another priority encode across the row to find the first cell, 
suppress that signal and find the next one - repeat until none left,
then clear all the supressions to allow a re-read.

I can describe it. but it seems quite expensive, but then FPGAs with more than 500 I/O are not cheap either.

Comment: The OP never said that the 512 control bits come from outside the FPGA. I have plenty of designs (on relatively modest FPGAs) in which buses of many hundreds of bits get connected between modules.

Answer (score 0):

This answer addresses the simplified problem described in your [second question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/589932/11683) (more about this at the end).

If the list is initially sorted, and you increment some subset of the elements by the same value, you can split the list into two sublists that are each still sorted -- the ones that didn't get incremented and those that did. You can then do a merge sort on those two lists.

This block diagram shows how the entire update cycle can be performed in two
phases that each require 2<sup>N</sup> clock cycles. In this question, you suggested that this would be an acceptable amount of time. In the first phase, you apply the increment and split the list into two sublists. In the second phase, you merge the sublists and load the next set of control inputs.

It took me a while to get Graphviz to produce a reasonable set of diagrams. Note that these diagrams are largely conceptual — there's a lot of detail missing with regard to initialization, multiplexing of addresses and timing.

The two images below show which paths are active during each of the phases of operation.

The logic is based on 2-port BRAMs and BRAM-based FIFOs, which means that it can generalize to a wide range of numbers of elements.

The element values are stored in one 2-port BRAM, while the control bits are stored in a second 2-port BRAM.

The actual sort is tag-based — in other words, rather than sorting the values directly, we sort the element indices (tags), such that when the tags are accessed in the given order, the element data values appear in their sorted order.

The tags are stored in FIFOs. One FIFO holds the sorted list at the beginning of phase 1. Two other FIFOs hold sub-lists of the tags, where each sub-list is also sorted.

**Phase 1**

[image: phase 1 activity]

At the beginning of phase 1, we assume that the "sorted element tags" FIFO contains the all of the tags, and that the "incr" register and the "element controls" contain the correct values for the next round of updates.

During phase 1, the tags are read out of the FIFO in sorted order. The tags are used to read both the "element values" and "element controls" BRAMs via their "B" ports, and this information is used to update the selected element values, which are written back into the BRAM via its "A" port. The element values can also be sent out of the system, since they represent the sorted results of the previous update cycle.

At the same time, the element controls are used to separate the tags into two sub-lists, those that have been modified and those that haven't, each of which is still sorted internally.

At the end of phase 1, the "sorted element tags" FIFO is empty, and the tags are all contained in the two "tag sublist" FIFOs.

**Phase 2**

[image: phase 2 activity]

During phase 2, the two tag sublists are merged back into a single sorted list. The tag at the head of each of the sublist FIFOs is used to look up the corresponding element value in the "element values" BRAM, using both of its ports. Both the element values and their indices (tags) are presented to the "merge tag sublists" logic so that it can select which tag should be forwarded to the "sorted element tags" FIFO.

Note that during phase 2, there's also an opportunity to update the "incr" register and the "element controls" BRAM for the next round of updates.

Note also that your original question divided the element list into three sublists, based on whether the element value stayed the same or was incremented or decremented by the "incr" value. This scheme supports that scenario, too. You just need to add a third sublist FIFO, and you need a second copy of the "element values" BRAM to provide a third read port during the merge phase.